# Saving whitin a loop with different variable names

Tags: r, function, save

I have a function that uses a list of data frames (`variables`) and gives as output two data frames (for every data frame in the list) which I want to save each one with a different variable name (instead of `up.val` and `down.val`) and different file names. Both, variable and file names I have store on a character vector that I've created.

```
  filtering_data <- function(x){

  x <- as.data.frame(x)
  pval <- which(x$P.Value < 0.05)
  pval <- x[pval,]


  up.pval <- which(pval$t > 0)
  down.pval <- which(pval$t < 0)

  up.pval <- pval[up.pval,]
  down.pval <- pval[down.pval,]

  save(up.pval, file = file.Rda)
  save(down.pval, file =  file.Rda )
  }

lapply(variables, filtering_data)
```

Comment: Just a side note, I would not recommend naming your function `filter` as there is already a base R function `filter` in the `stats` namespace.

Comment: Thanks, I'll change the name of the function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `assign` to assign the values to new names, and then provide the variable names as the `list` argument to `save`. as in:

```
filtering_data <- function(x,varName,file.rda){ 

    [calculations go here]]

    # assign() only assigns one value so check the length of varName
    stopifnot(length(varName)==1)

    # make the new variable names
    name.up <- paste0(varName,'.','up')
    name.down <- paste0(varName,'.','down')

    # assign the values to them in the current environment
    assign(name.up,up.pval)
    assign(name.down,down.pval)

    # save the named variables
    save(list=name.up,  file=file.rda)
    save(list=name.down,file=file.rda)
}
```

Incidentally, `file.rda` should probably be an argument, rather than assuming it's already defined

Comment: Not working. If I add more variables to the function like `varName` it returns me something like `Error en pval$t : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`.

If I add the las four lines of code I get an error like this : `Error en save(list = up_varNames, file = file.Rda) : objects ‘top_k1.up’, ‘top_k2.up’, ‘top_Na1.up’, ‘top_Na2.up’, ‘top_ox.up’, ‘top_ter.up’, ‘top_ypd.up’ not found ` 
and 
`Message of lost
1: In assign(up_varNames, up.pval) :
  just the first element is used as name of a variable`
The same for the other assign line.

Comment: That is because `assign` only assigns one variable to the current environment.  You would have to loop over variable names (`for(i in seq_along(name.up)) assign(name.up[i],up.pval[i]) ).  That is why you are getting the error message from `save`.

Comment: the error about `pval$t`  is telling you that `pval` is an atomic vector (probably numeric; you can use `class(pval)` to find out).  Since `t` is not defined in your post, there's no way for me to know what `t` is and why you're using it. In any case, the `$` operator is not defined for vectors.  Maybe you want `pval[t]`

Comment: Ok, know I get two files `(.Rda)`, (I get two because I've saved all this just in two files, the up.Rda and the down.Rda to make it easier), but each files has 8 data frames (which is ok the number), but all are the same (like the las data frame of the list). So I guess this is due to the way of loop for within the function.

Comment: `t` and `P.Value` are columns of the data frame that I use to filter the information I want.

Comment: you should use `pval <- x[which(x$P.Value < 0.05),]` instead, since in your first definition of `pval` it is an interger, and it's confusing when the same variable names is used for different objects throughout your code.